# Using Alamofire to POST and parse response | Swift 5

Tags: swift, alamofire

I have the following JSON that that is produced when the paramater `occupation` is POST:

```
[
    {
        "group": "GR2923",
        "number": "0239039",
    }
]
```

I need to parse this data in Swift and assign the value of `group` to the variable `groupValue` and the value of number to the variable `numberValue`.

**I have tried using something like this but I am not sure how to implement the JSON array I have into Alamofire:**

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
  .responseJSON { response in
      if response.data != nil {
        let json = JSON(data: response.data!)
        let name = json["group"][0][""].string
        if name != nil {
          print(name!)
        }
      }
  }
```

Comment: Are you using SwiftyJSON to parse the response?

Comment: No just Alamofire

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get)
  .responseJSON { response in
    if let value = response.value {
        let json = JSON(value).arrayValue
        if let name = json[0]["group"].string {
             print(name!)
         }
     }
}
```

For post request with params you can use this

```
 func getResult(url:String, paramKey:[String], paramValue:[Any], completion: @escaping (Bool, Any?) -> Void) {

        let _headers : HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"]
        let params : Parameters = getParams(paramKey: paramKey, paramValue: paramValue)

        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            completion(false, nil)
            return
        }

        Alamofire.request(url,
                          method: .post,
                          parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody , headers: _headers)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in

                guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                    completion(false, nil)
                    return
                }

                if let value = response.result.value{
                    let json = JSON(value)

                    if json["status_code"].stringValue == "200" {
                        completion(true, json)
                    } else {
                        completion(false, json)
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    func getParams(paramKey:[String], paramValue:[Any]) -> [String:Any] {

        var dictionary =  [String:Any]()

        dictionary.updateValue(Constants.API_TOKEN, forKey: HTTPParams.PARAM_API_TOKEN)

        for index in 0..<paramKey.count {
            dictionary.updateValue(paramValue[index], forKey: paramKey[index])
        }

        return dictionary
    }
```

And from **ViewController** you can use this to call

```
    let url = "Your API Url"
    let params = ["occupation"] // Param key
    let paramValues = ["doctor"] // Param values  
   // UrlRequest the file name where the method is placed 
    UrlRequest().getResult(url: url, paramKey: params, paramValue: paramValues) { (success, data) in
        if success {
          // Success result with data
        }else{
            // Failed 
        }
    }
```

Comment: I need to POST the parameter `occupation` to first get a response. How are the parameters written in Alamofire?

Comment: I really appreciate your help, please let me know if you have any questions?

Comment: @MarkPalson Check my updated answer. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I am a bit confused, what would go in params and paraValues? In my example if the parameter I need to POST before getting results is "occupation": "doctor" which would that go into?

Comment: Updated answer with  "occupation": "doctor" example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to parse json. First you have to check json value is NSDictionary or not.

```
  Alamofire.request(stringURL, method: .get)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let value = response.result.value as? NSDictionary {
                //    print(value)

                if let group =   value["group"] as? String {
                //    print(group)

}
}
}
```